# A Single Word For Person without any bad habits

Tags: single-word-requests

A person without any vices is known as....

A person without any bad habits is known as or called as.....

Comment: A "fictional character"

Comment: “Called as” is not English. Just “called”.

Answer (score 3):

An informal *single word* as asked for could be, as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/saint) gives, a

> **saint**
> NOUN
>
> **2** *informal* A very virtuous, kind, or patient person.

---

As a *phrase*, the person could be called a **paragon of virtue**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/paragon) says

> **paragon**
> NOUN
>
> **1** A person or thing regarded as a perfect example of a particular quality.
> *it would have taken a paragon of virtue not to feel viciously jealous*

---

The [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/virtue) entry for *virtue* is

> **virtue**
> NOUN
>
> **1** Behaviour showing high moral standards.
> *The man was one of great virtue, and his morals were admired by everyone.*

Answer (score 0):

Tough one, maybe a god? But on a much serious note you can use words like ***unblemished***, ***immaculate***, ***flawless***, ***letter-perfect***, ***picture-perfect***,***impeccable*** to define such a person. Though i don't think there is a single exact word which would define  him/her. But these will do.

Answer (score -1):

How about **boy scout**? From M-W:

> **[boy scout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Boy%20Scout)**: a person whose values or actions are characteristic of a Boy Scout

> [Boy scout principles and values](http://boyscoutsofamerica.orghub.net/posts/explore/boy-scout-principles-and-values.html#:%7E:text=Scout%20Law%20%20%20A%20Scout%20is%3A%20,a%20brot%20...%20%208%20more%20rows%20)

Your examples:

> A person without any vices is known as a **boy scout**.

> A person without any bad habits is known as or called a **boy scout**.

An **eagle scout** goes beyond an ordinary **boy scout** in terms of exemplifying the values and character of a **boy scout**. Again from M-W:

> **[eagle scout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eagle%20scput)**: a Boy Scout who has reached the highest level of achievement in scouting; a straight-arrow and self-reliant man

This suggests **straight arrow** as yet a third possiiblity. From M-W:

> **[straight arrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight%20arrow)**: a person who lives by rigidly proper or conventional standards